# Where do you the get the index values to use when calling PowerWriteACValueIndex?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, powershell, winapi

When using the [`PowerWriteACValueIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372765.aspx) where do you the get the index values for every power setting?

The GUIDs I'm using are from wdm.h and they are: `GUID_STANDBY_TIMEOUT`, `GUID_HIBERNATE_TIMEOUT` and `GUID_ALLOW_STANDBY_STATES`.

I'm making a WPF application in C# (I've imported `PowerWriteACValueIndex` using an attribute)

Comment: I made some edits to clarify your question and simplify the title a bit. If you disagree with the changes, feel free to click the link above my username (where it says "edited X ago") and hit the rollback link to take it back to your original revision.

Comment: no its fine thanks a lot it looks better now.

Comment: Anybody?? I need help with this badly. its been 3 days and I still have the same problem :(